# How to configure local DynamoDB as ASP.NET session state provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-dynamodb

I have been tasked to write a proof of concept for using Amazon's DynamoDB service to store ASP.NET session state. I downloaded Amazon's local DynamoDB server from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html), and got it running successfully. I created a test MVC website, and added the following NuGet packages.

```
<package id="AWS.SessionProvider" version="3.1.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="AWSSDK.Core" version="3.1.4.3" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2" version="3.1.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

I added the following to `web.config`.

```
    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DynamoDB">
        <providers>
            <add name="DynamoDB" type="Amazon.SessionProvider.DynamoDBSessionStateStore" AWSProfileName="" Region="" />
        </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

Now I'm stuck. Amazon's documentation for local DynamoDB only talks about defining the service URL, not profile or region settings. Amazon's [documentation for the session provider](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/V2/DeveloperGuide/net-dg-dynamodb-session.html) only talks about using a real online DynamoDB service with real credentials. The only mention I can find online of setting the service URL assumes that you are creating a DynamoDB client in code for arbitrary data access. I can't seem to find any overlap between these three concepts. Can anyone tell me how to configure local DynamoDB only as a session provider without referencing real Amazon credentials or regions?

Answer (score 0):

Set the attribute `ServiceUrl="http://localhost:8000/"`

```
    <sessionState timeout="20" mode="Custom" customProvider="DynamoDBSessionStoreProvider">
<providers>
  <add
    name="DynamoDBSessionStoreProvider"
    type="Amazon.SessionProvider.DynamoDBSessionStateStore"
    AWSProfileName="default"
    AWSAccessKey="must be real"
    AWSSecretKey="must be real values"
    Region="eu-west-1"
    ServiceUrl="http://localhost:8000/" />
</providers>
</sessionState>
```

Source:

> https://github.com/aws/aws-dotnet-session-provider/blob/master/src/DynamoDBSessionStateStore.cs#L87